# How to detect iBeacon in Android?

Tags: android, detect, ibeacon-android

It is the first time I work with iBeacon. So can you tell me how to detect it(give me some code example). Thanks very much. It is very important to me.

Answer (score 6):

The open source [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/) will allow you to do this.

Here is a basic code sample:

```
public class MonitoringActivity extends Activity implements IBeaconConsumer {
  protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
  private IBeaconManager iBeaconManager = IBeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
    iBeaconManager.bind(this);
  }
  @Override 
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    iBeaconManager.unBind(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
    iBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
      Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an iBeacon for the firt time!");       
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
      Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an iBeacon");
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing iBeacons: "+state);     
    }
    });

    try {
        iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
  }

}
```

Full disclosure: I am Chief Engineer for Radius Networks and author of the library.

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung I write a class not extend activity as your example. But it can not run onIBeaconServiceConnect(). Can you tell me the reason. I overwrite some menthod of IBeaconConsumer as:

Comment: Hi @davidgyoung can you show me how to write a class implements IBeaconConsumer without activity Thanks very much.
Here is my code https://app.box.com/s/340hm5hp257n464lsg8f. I don not know why onIBeaconServiceConnect() does not run. Thanks you

Comment: In the code you shared, I do not see any call to iBeaconManager.bind(...) which is necessary to get a callback to onIBeaconServiceConnect().  If you need more help, please post a new question that includes your code inline, that way everybody else can see it, too and be able to offer their answers.

Comment: Thanks you. I got over this problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello sir I made a similar code as it is above by onIBeaconServiceConnect()  is not called in my activity but i am able to run the demo app without any problem. What i would have missed? any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer to your question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624467/onibeaconserviceconnect-is-not-getting-called-in-android/23629291#23629291

Comment: monitor ibeacon proximity and i want to show something please if you can help me

Comment: @jay-thakkar, can you pease create a new question?

Comment: @davidgyoung I found the solution from radiusnetworks.com.. Thanks !!